# Only one value returns from while loop function

Tags: python

I am trying to make a python script that loads a few excel documents and tries to collect data.

Right now i am trying to return all the data from one column, however it seems that when i use the for loop in `grab_index_id` it only returns the first value on the column, `index id`.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

doc1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('sp_schema.xlsx')
master_sheet = doc1.get_sheet_by_name('Master List')

doc2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('slc.xlsx')
slc_sheet = doc2.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

def grab_index_id():
     i = 0
     x = 1
     while i < 10:
        return (master_sheet.cell(row = x, column = 1).value)
        x = x + 1
        i = i + 1

print(grab_index_id())
```

> INDEX ID
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Because you return the function without doing anything...

Comment: The dual counters bothers the heck out of me, `for x in range(10):` and `row = x+1` would take out 4 lines.

Comment: @tgikal im still learning the ropes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `return` will return a value and end the function.
To return a list you should use:

```
def grab_index_id():
   return [master_sheet.cell(row = x, column = 1).value for x in range(1,12)]
```

Comment: It appears that when i try to print it nothing is being outputted.

Comment: Can give me more details?

Comment: I used your solution for this function, but when i try to run the program, there is no output at all. Perhaps a logical error?

Comment: You can try return [master_sheet.cell(row = x, column = 1).value for x in range(1,12)], that should be correct

Comment: I got it to work, Thank You! I am still very new to python and this one line saved a lot of space!

Comment: Read about list compression in python, it's a great tool and will be useful to you!